# How to reduce the sweetness of a cake recipe without reducing the sugar

Tags: cake

I am experimenting with cake recipes for my son's wedding. His fiancé wants a vanilla almond cake, and I have found a recipe that is nearly perfect, but a little too sweet. I have tried simply reducing the sugar, but even reducing it a small amount messes with the texture of the cake. I am trying to find if there is a way to tone down the sweetness without changing the texture or tenderness of the cake. Any suggestions?

Comment: Frankly no, you can't make it less sweet without reducing the sugar. However, if you post the complete recipe and method we can help you reduce the sugar and balance the other ingredients.

Comment: In some cakes (e.g. lemon, fruit, or even coffee) you can offset the sweetness, but it's hard to see how in that one.  The full recipe might give some ideas, but it's not a simple substitution

Comment: Consider using a less sweet frosting, or a drizzle of a citrus syrup to offset the perceived sweetness.  Also remember that if you are stacking a cake, you do  **not** want it light and fluffy or it might not have the structural integrity for lower layers; you want something more like pound cake

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's been over a day and the poster has not edited with the recipe, it's therefore unanswerable as there's not enough detail.